# Docker Environment Vraiable

Tags: docker

I am implementing docker client API,But I stuck in the middle.Can anyone help me to set the environment variable i.e registryUser, registryPass, registryMail, registryUrl, withDockerCertPath.

```
public class Example1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // DockerClient dockerClient = DockerClientBuilder.getInstance("tcp://192.168.0.199:2375").build();

        DockerClientConfig config = DefaultDockerClientConfig.createDefaultConfigBuilder()
            .withDockerHost("tcp://192.168.0.199:2375")
            .withDockerTlsVerify(true)
            .withDockerCertPath("/home/user/.docker")
            .withRegistryUsername(registryUser)
            .withRegistryPassword(registryPass)
            .withRegistryEmail(registryMail)
            .withRegistryUrl(registryUrl)
            .build();
        Info info =  dockerClient.infoCmd().exec();
        System.out.println("info ===="+info.toString());
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Why do you need those? All you're running is `info`.

Comment: Actually, I installed docker on 192.168.0.199 "Centos". and I want to get the container information in java from 192.168.0.199 and will store the container information including network information in the database.

Comment: So why do you need image registry information?